Text-align: center. Works for Header, not for Content
I've tried everything here, but I am sure it's something obvious.


.columnPages header {text-align: center;}
.columnPages content {text-align: center;}
<div class="columnPages">
<header>This is the Header<br /><br />
</header>
<content>This is the content.
</content>
</div>



This is the result:

For some reason, the Header centres, but not the Content. Can anyone explain why there is a difference?
Many thanks
Tried rearranging all the options, changing Left to Right and to Justify

content is not a native tag, so it should have no styling applied to it, making it an inline block, which would mean your text is centered, but the block just has the width of the text. Try adding display: block to your <content> element. Note: I have converted your code to a a little snippet with the code in it so we can see it live and debug it with you. An image just isn't as clear as an actual rendering of the browser and code. It's that <> button in the SO editor that allows you to add a snippet of HTML.

i think i'ts cause u -use content instead of div ,div would take all the width of container and then center correctly...
to behave like div i would add:       display: block; to columnspages.content section.
.columnPages content {text-align: center;  display: block;}

Thank you for the help. As a comparative novice, it is much appreciated!

The main problem is that you are using a custom html tag that does not have a defined width. You can check this by adding a background to content tag.
The simplest solution is to change the content tag to main tag.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp


.columnPages header {
  text-align: center;
}
.columnPages main {
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="columnPages">
    <header>This is the Header<br><br></header>
    <main>This is the content.</main>
</div>




The simplest solution is to add display: block; to the style rules - mostly because custom elements are a thing and you would need this knowledge there as well.

For content add display:block in order to center align content. content is an inline element, and it does not take full width. So, text-align: center has no effect unless we make it a block element.


<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .columnPages header {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .columnPages content {
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="columnPages">
        <header>This is the Header<br /><br />
        </header>
        <content>This is the content.
        </content>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




<div class="columnPages">
    <header>This is the Header</header>
    <p>This is the content.</p>
</div>



.columnPages header, p{text-align: center;}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Add CSS to the content tag. Give it the following property:
display: block;


This answer was already provided with more details

@DarkBee oh, I didn't notice.
